# set PHP variable with Tasker / HTTP Get/Post Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, html, http, raspberry-pi, tasker

So I have this code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_var']))
  {
  $formvalue = $_POST['input_value'];
  exec('sudo python LCD_Log_Write.py ' .$formvalue);
  }
?>

<form action="?submit =true" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="input_value">
<input type="submit" name="submit_var">
```

which is a text box and a submit button, when the button is pressed the text in the text box shows up on an LCD connected to my Raspberry Pi.
My question is how do I automate filling in this text box and clicking this button with Tasker? If you're not familiar with Tasker it can use HHTP gets, posts and Heads so if you know how to do it with that you would also be a huge help to me! Thank you!

Comment: On what are you using Tasker?

Comment: @Trevor On my Nexus 5 phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve what you need by using Web interface and automating input / clicking, but that would be very inefficient. Best approach is, indeed, using http post.

Assuming that the code is run when IP 1.2.3.4 is used, you'd create a `http post` task and you fill it in like that:

`server:port` 1.2.3.4

`path` /index.php (if that's the file you're using)

`data / file` input_value=%txt_var

submit_var=true

`content-type` x-www-form-urlencoded

If it still doesn't work, leave `content-type` empty.

And that should do. 
Please note the new line in `data / file` field. 
Also, the %txt_var is a tasker variable to be filled in prior to sending the http post request

Since you'd have it done this way you could alter your php code, leaving only first 7 lines (as the rest would not be needed) or go even further and leave only line 4 and 5

Alternatively, if the `if` is required, change it to check whether `input_value` is set and not empty

Comment: Using this with the content-type field empty worked, with "x-www-form-urlencoded" in it it didn't. Thanks a lot! I feel stupid now since I really should've just tried this. Anyway, thanks a lot and have a nice day!!